# Are these integrals equivalent?

Tags: integration, notation

So I have the following integral:

$$\int_0^2 \frac{dt}{4+t^2}$$

In order to solve it am I able to say it is equivalent to the following integral?

$$\int_0^2 \frac{1}{4+t^2} dt$$

If not how can I go about solving it. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the first is shorthand for the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question, but yes, the notation $\int \frac{dx}{f(x)}$ does mean $\int \frac{1}{f(x)} \ dx$.